# can a character take a dash action multiple times in one round?

Tags: dnd-5e

if a character is given the ability to take the dash action as a bonus action or take multiple actions on the same turn, can said character use all of them to take the dash action?

considering a wood-elf, monk-fighter multiclass with a bunch of wizard friends about to take part in an Olympic event. the wizards sneak up and caste haste, longstrider, and expedited retreat on him at the same time. the person would have a base movement of 65 feet + 10 feet for longstrider and 3 dash actions per turn. (5 with action surge) with a movement speed of 225 ft per round (37.5 ft per second) or 375 ft/round (62.5 ft/s) with action surge. other than local traffic laws is this scenario valid RAW.

addendum; if it is possible to take multiple dash actions on the same turn, can a rogue attempt to hide multiple times on a single turn?

Comment: At least this isn't faster than the speed of light which was possible in 3.5 - bounded accuracy at work!

Comment: Please ask your question about hiding multiple times as a separate question.